# How to return array through a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get an array to split so I can use the data as an anchor href tag. I can get the arrays to log in the console, but every `menu-link` href is linking to `#News`.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($('.newsletter-accordion').find('.headline_title').length > 0) {

        var all = $(".headline_title").map(function() {
            return this.innerHTML;
        });

        console.log(all);

        for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    
            $('.headline_title').contents().unwrap().appendTo($('#newsletter-nav ul')).wrap('<li><a class="menu-link" href="#' + all[i] + '" ></a></li>');
            console.log(all[i])
          }
    }

});
```

I'm appending the data to an `id` of newsletter `nav` to be used as a navigation throughout the page. I'm not sure if I'm calling it correctly with the `+ all[i]`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

my json console log.

```
{"0":"News","1":"Gallery Title","2":"tyest","length":3,"prevObject":{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"length":3,"prevObject":{"0":{"location":{"ancestorOrigins":{},"href":"https://croydon.vm/newsletters/4th-march-2022/#News","origin":"https://croydon.vm","protocol":"https:","host":"croydon.vm","hostname":"croydon.vm","port":"","pathname":"/newsletters/4th-march-2022/","search":"","hash":"#News"},"jQuery32100224421490645290161":{"events":{"webkitvisibilitychange":[{"type":"webkitvisibilitychange","origType":"webkitvisibilitychange","guid":11,"namespace":""}],"ready":[{"type":"ready","origType":"ready","guid":7,"namespace":"slick.slick-0"}],"click":[{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":16,"selector":".accordion-btn","needsContext":false,"namespace":""}]},"focusout":1,"focusin":1},"jQuery360044517605261132511":{"events":{"ajaxSuccess":[{"type":"ajaxSuccess","origType":"ajaxSuccess","guid":1428,"namespace":""}],"touchstart":[{"type":"touchstart","origType":"touchstart","guid":1434,"selector":".qm-resizer","needsContext":false,"namespace":""}],"mousedown":[{"type":"mousedown","origType":"mousedown","guid":1434,"selector":".qm-resizer","needsContext":false,"namespace":""}]}}},"length":1}}}
```

im using flexible content also so this is one of the blocks of html

```
<section class="newsletter-accordion">

    <?php
      $headline = get_sub_field('section_headline');
    ?>

    <h1 class="headline_title" id="<?php echo $headline; ?>"><?php echo $headline; ?></h1>
    <h1 class="" id="<?php echo $headline; ?>"><?php echo $headline; ?></h1>

    <div class="grid_container">
        <div class="row single_content__wrapper justify-content-center ">
```

it's calling the h1 headline title, this headline title appears on other blocks also.

Comment: It's very difficult to help you unless we can see the content of `all`. Please provide the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(all));` then we can have the data in a usable format. (If it's too long, just provide a reasonable sample).

Comment: thanks for your reply @ADyson - i have updated the OP as requested.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also  show the HTML you're working with, specifically the bit(s) which the `$(".headline_title")` selector would match. Need to see the HTML structure within the element(s) matched by that class.

Comment: @ADyson brill - i've updated the code

Comment: The finished HTML (as delivered to the browser) would be better, rather than peppered with PHP code, because your JS code operates on the finished HTML, not the PHP. Where does "News" appear in that, for example? Can we assume it's the result of `echo $headline`?

Comment: That's correct @ADyson - i'm setting the id of the section as the variable - i need to interpret that into the jquery code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time your `for` loop runs, the `.contents().unwrap()...`etc code grabs *all* the items with the "headline_title" class and moves them into the nav, wrapping them in a link. But of course in each one the link you're creating to wrap around each element it's moved uses the the first item from `all`, which is "News".

Next time the loop iterates, there's nothing left for `.contents()` to grab anymore, so nothing happens.

Instead, since `.wrap()` gives us the option to use a callback function, whose `this` context variable represents the current element in the matched set, we can dispense with `all` and the loop entirely:

```js
$('.headline_title').contents().unwrap().appendTo($('#newsletter-nav ul')).wrap(function() {
  return '<li><a class="menu-link" href="#' + $(this).text() + '" ></a></li>';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="headline_title">News</h1>
<h1 class="headline_title">Gallery Title</h1>
<h1 class="headline_title">tyest</h1>

<div id="newsletter-nav">
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: Worked a treat - i also updated this `$(this).text().replace(/ /g, "-").toLowerCase()` and now everything is working spot on. Cheers mate.